# ffmpeg GIF to WebM decoding issue

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, webm

I'm trying to convert GIF files into WebM (ffmpeg, libvpx) and getting some strange ffmpeg behaviour.

ffmpeg is installed on my mac from MacPorts.

Converting with:

```
ffmpeg -i srcFilename.gif -b:v 600K -qmin 0 -qmax 50 -crf 5 destFilename.webm
```

if my GIF file has some frame(s) with 1-2s duration somewhere in the middle of animation like [this](http://i39.tinypic.com/2v8fwy1.gif), conversion result is fine - it's playing with the "pause" in the middle.

But if I have GIF like [this](http://i41.tinypic.com/2rxttth.gif) with "pause" in the last frame, ffmpeg decodes it without a delay.

Have no idea why, spent some time reading ffmpeg manual, trying different conversion options with no success.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Output for file 1 http://pastebin.com/TKYfypHk with delay in the middle. Output for file 2 http://pastebin.com/XHxKm6dQ with delay in the end

Comment: same thing happened to me. it also happens if i convert to mp4

Comment: @Ramin no, and the issue is still opened in ffmpeg bug tracker. Using hack mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an email to GIF decoder author and he answered me that he knows about this issue. It's located somewhere deep inside of ffmpeg and he has no idea how to fix it right now.

So, I'm using "dirty hack" in my project - just adding copy of last frame with zero delay to GIF file before encoding.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, could you go further into detail about your hack and how to implement it?

Comment: @Ramin implementation depends of programming language and a library you're using to work with gifs. I'd recommend you just to add a transparent frame into the end of a gif. It should work.